# React - separate boxes with continuous typing

Tags: reactjs, textbox

I want to create a component which looks like this:

[image]

Every field contains 2 digits. When filling the first field with 2 digits the cursor is moved to the second field automatically, etc.

In React-native, there's the component TextInput which is very suitable for my case.

Do you have any suggestion how to do it in React?

Comment: Define maxlength as 2 for textbox, when maxlength is reached, focus on next textbox using ref.

Comment: I have updated my answer

Answer (score 2):

In order to manipulate DOM elements make use of `refs`.On mount,let the focus be on the first input element and rest of the elements be `blur`.Once the data is filled,move the focus from one input element to another.

```
class App extends React.Component{
      state = {
        firstValue : "",
        secValue: "",
        thirdValue : ""
      }
      componentDidMount(){
        this.firstInput.focus();
       this.secInput.blur();
       this.thirdInput.blur();
      }
      onChange = (e)=>{
      if(this.firstInput.value.length == 2){
          this.secInput.focus();
      }
      if(this.secInput.value.length == 2){
          this.thirdInput.focus();
      }
       this.setState({
         [e.target.name] = [e.target.value]
       });
      }
      render() {
        return(
          <div>
            <input 
              maxlength = "2"
              ref={(input) => { this.firstInput = input; }} 
              value={this.state.firstValue}
              onChange = {this.Change}
            />
           <input 
              maxlength = "2"
              ref={(input) => { this.secInput = input; }} 
              value={this.state.secValue}
              onChange = {this.Change}
            />
            <input 
              maxlength = "2"
              ref={(input) => { this.thirdInput = input; }} 
              value={this.state.thirdValue}
              onChange = {this.Change}
            />
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```